# Returning INTEGER from IF statement in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.p_create_new_message
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @li_count               INTEGER         
    IF @li_count <> 2
    BEGIN
        RETURN 11;
    END
    RETURN 12;
END
```

I would expect to get `11`, but I get `12`.  Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I don't think it is good practice to use stored procedures to return values, unless they are specifically status values.  Instead, use an `output` parameter.

But the reason is because the default value of `@li_count` is `NULL`.  Almost all comparisons with `NULL` return either `NULL` or `false` -- both of which are not true.

I think the procedure should be written as:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.p_create_new_message (
    @retval INTEGER OUTPUT
) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @li_count INTEGER ;        

    IF @li_count <> 2 OR @li_count IS NULL
    BEGIN
        @retval = 11;
        return;
    END;
    @retval = 12;
END;
```

Comment: Thank you.  Surprising that `null <> 2` doesn't resolve...  I'll accept as soon as I can (it says 10 mins)

Answer (score 0):

NULL is not a value, can not compare with other value directly

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.p_create_new_message
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @li_count               INTEGER         
   IF ISNULL(@li_count,0) <> 2
   BEGIN
      RETURN 11;
   END
  RETURN 12;
END
```